# Request Tracker migrate PostgreSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, request-tracker

I am in the process of migrating a request tracker 3.6 instance from one server to another.  The old server uses PostgreSQL and the new one will use MySQL.  Is there a way to migrate the data from one database to another?

Comment: Out of interest, why the migration?

Comment: I love PostgreSQL but in this case the destination server already has MySQL for some other systems data and so it does not make sense to run PostgreSQL just for Request Tracker.  It would be just one more system to maintain and backup.

Comment: Fairly sane reason :) Here, have a +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching and getting the terms correct I came across the following:
http://rt.bestpractical.com/view/PgToMySQL and linked from there is a Perl script that will do the required migration.  It will need DBI and the mysql & postgresql drivers but seems to work pretty well.